# RealVNC Viewer doesn't accept keyboard input

Tags: pi-4, vnc, windows, ethernet-port

I followed this [guide](https://www.instructables.com/Set-Up-Raspberry-Pi-4-Through-Laptoppc-Using-Ether/) to connect my raspberry to my computer, but when i connected with RealVNC Viewer, it does not accept keyboard or mouse input. I am on a Windows 11 computer, Raspberry Pi 4, and am connecting the ethernet cable to my computer via an ethernet to USB-C adapter.

Comment: I'm not sure you can use an 'ethernet to USB-C adapter'... do you not have a regular Ethernet cable to try?

Comment: I do, but my computer does not have an ethernet port.

Comment: To further complicate the matter, my old computer, which I just found does have an ethernet port, doesn't work when connected via ethernet, but does work via ethernet to USB-C adapter.

Comment: I don't ***know*** that the USBC-Ethernet adapter ***won't*** work... but you'll need to do more research & reading to try to learn this.